# How to pass multiple arrays in tcl proc?

Tags: arrays, tcl, procedure

`enter code here`

I want to pass multiple arrays to tcl proc for a specific task.

say I have List of Array Names

```
set array_names [list abc pqr xyz]
```

each array contains

```
array set abc {
      red true
      blue false
      green true
      yellow false
}
array set pqr {
      red false
      blue true
      green false
      yellow true
}
```

same for xyz array

Without proc I am able to perform below task 
but need to create a proc for the same

```
foreach RS $array_names {
   foreach {arr_ind ind_value} [array get $RS] {
       puts "set $RS\_$arr_ind $ind_value"
}}
```

It will output

```
set abc_yellow false
set abc_blue false
set abc_green true
set abc_red true
set pqr_yellow true
set pqr_blue true
set pqr_green false
set pqr_red false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `upvar` command to achieve this.

```
 proc test {array_names} {
        foreach elem $array_names {
                upvar $elem __array
                foreach {arr_ind ind_value} [array get __array] {
                        puts "set $elem\_$arr_ind $ind_value"
                }
        }
}
```

Call the procedure as,

```
test $array_names
```

**Reference :** [upvar](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm)